# Python Predict Value for customer in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python and I am at a wall
I want to predict values for the customers

```
data = { 
         “Hana”: 
         {
              “shirt”: 45.00,
              “pants”: 30.00,
              “shoes”: 80.00
          },
         “Jill”: 
         {
              “Hat”: 10.00,
              “shirt”: 40.00
          },
         “Mary”: 
         {
              “Hat”: 20.00,
              “pants”: 30.00,
              “shoes”: 65.00
          }
    }
```

I want to predict the missing key values for each of the customers 
Ex: Hana bought a hat for pred_value
    Jill bought a pants for pred_value and shoes for pred_value
    Mart bought a shirt for pred_value

Comment: Have you done anything to try to solve this? Smells homeworky

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for a little more? Are you saying you want to be able to find out which item is missing from each person's wardrobe in the dictionary?